# Detect and Save Cookies / localStorage while Web Scraping in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, web-scraping

I am working on scraping some data, but the website validates my request by checking cookies. I get one "free" page, then it expects me to have some localStorage or cookies set. It usually sets 3-5 cookies on page load.

I am not sure what to do, or how to save the cookies. I have seen how to add cookies to my code before I compile it, but that only works if I navigate using Firefox/Chrome and get the cookie data from them. The site's javascript is obfuscated, so I can't just regex parse it. I am using ScrapySharp, HtmlAgilityPack, and just regular old HttpClient interchangabley to try saving the cookies.

I call the `GetContent` method, and need to save the cookies / localStorage info somewhere so I can use it again the next time I call it.

```
public static CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
public static string GetContent(string url, string referrer= "https://www.google.com")
{
    HttpClientHandler newhandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(newhandler);
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, CurrentOffice.url);
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Referer", referrer);
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");

     //If I can detect them, I can add cookies here like this
    cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("CookieName", "cookie_value"));

    var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
    var httpContent = httpResponseMessage.Content;
    string result = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return result;
}
```

I am hoping someone has dealt with this as well and has a suggestion. Alternatively maybe I could try blocking the javascript from running and redirecting me to a 405 page.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. Is it "How do I read cookies with `HttpClient`" ?

Comment: Yes, but the cookies seem to be rendered using obfuscated js code that is included using the `defer` keyword, not sure if any of that matters.

Comment: Sounds like the company that made the site really doesn't want people to scrape their website...

Comment: `HttpClient` is not going to execute any javascript. It will only read cookies set by the  server.

Comment: have you tried using an engine such as Selenium to perform this task?

Comment: I ended up using a randomly rotating proxy. It takes a bit longer, but it works.